# Moq why do mocked methods return null and tests till pass?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, model-view-controller, moq

I am trying to mock the two interfaces below.

```cs
Mock<IEmailSender> emailSender = new Mock<IEmailSender>();
Mock<IEmailTemplate> emailTemplate = new Mock<IEmailTemplate>();
```

Here is the setup

```cs
emailTemplate.Setup(x => x.GetForgotPasswordTemplate(It.IsAny<EmailTemplateViewModel>())).Returns(It.IsAny<string>());
emailSender.Setup(x => x.SendEmailAsync(It.IsAny<SendEmailViewModel>(), default)).ReturnsAsync(It.IsAny<SendEmailResultViewModel>());
```

Here is the controller action that is called.

```cs
[EnableCors(PolicyName = "AllowClientAccess")]
[HttpGet("Forgot")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ForgotPassword([FromQuery] string email)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
    if (user != null)
    {
        //MOQ file path not found
        EmailTemplateViewModel model = new EmailTemplateViewModel();
        model.Email = email;
        model.RecipientName = user.UserName;

        var message = _emailTemplate.GetForgotPasswordTemplate(model);

        SendEmailViewModel sendEmailViewModel = new SendEmailViewModel();

        sendEmailViewModel.RecipientName = user.UserName;
        sendEmailViewModel.RecipientEmail = user.Email;
        sendEmailViewModel.Subject = "ForgotPassword";
        sendEmailViewModel.Body = message;

        await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(sendEmailViewModel);
        return Ok(AddSuccess("Check your email", "Forgot Password"));
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError("Forgot Password","Unable to send email");
    return BadRequest(ModelErrors());
}
```

This line returns null

> var message = _emailTemplate.GetForgotPasswordTemplate(model);

Here is the method code

```cs
public string GetForgotPasswordTemplate(EmailTemplateViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        var utcNow = DateTime.Now;
        if (_testEmailTemplate == null)
            if (File.Exists("Helpers/Templates/ForgotPasswordEmail.template"))
                _testEmailTemplate = ReadPhysicalFile("Helpers/Templates/ForgotPasswordEmail.template");

        var appUrl = _configuration.GetSection("ApplicationUrl").Value +
                     "/reset-password?&email=" + model.Email;
        var emailMessage = _testEmailTemplate
            .Replace("{user}", model.RecipientName)
            .Replace("{testDate}", utcNow.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            .Replace("{appUrl}", appUrl);

        return emailMessage;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.Warning(e, "Email error");
        throw;
    }
}
```

This line also returns null

> await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(sendEmailViewModel);

Here is the method code

```cs
public Task<SendEmailResultViewModel> SendEmailAsync(SendEmailViewModel model, SmtpConfig config = default)
{
    model.IsHtml = true;
    
    var from = new MailboxAddress(_config.FromName, _config.FromEmail);
    var to = new MailboxAddress(model.RecipientName, model.RecipientEmail);

    return SendEmailAsync(@from, new[] {to}, model.Body, model.Body, config, model.IsHtml);
}
```

Here is the test

```cs
[Theory]
[InlineData("stephen@kaizenappz.com")]
public async Task WhenAUserForgetsPasswordAHttpStatusCode200ShouldBeReturnedAsync(string email)
{
    var confirmUser = await Controller.ForgotPassword(email);

    var result = confirmUser as OkObjectResult;

    var actual = (HttpStatusCode)result?.StatusCode.Value;
    var expected = HttpStatusCode.OK;

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

However the test passes and what i am wondering is why do both of these methods return null and why does the test pass even though it returns null. How do i get these to return something?

One thing I do not understand is when to use It.Any and just pass in a normal object with some test data. How am i supposed to check a user exists if i use It.Any and i need to pass a model into my controller action?

Comment: Where is the test? None of the code you posted actually uses the items that you say are being returned as null, so nothing will break (in that code, at least).

Comment: posted @MatthewWatson why does it matter?

Comment: @geekman For me this `Returns(It.IsAny<string>())` is really weird. I normally use `It` only just in a Setup phase. (Others prefer to use that at `Verify` calls as well). Have you tried to specify explicit values, like `.Returns("myTestResult")`?

Comment: @PeterCsala i will try it and let you know thanks.    fakeUserManager.Setup(x => x.AddClaimsAsync(createUser, claims)).ReturnsAsync(IdentityResult.Success); this is also returning null. But this         fakeUserManager.Setup(x => x.RemoveClaimsAsync(user, claims)).ReturnsAsync(IdentityResult.Success); does not return null.

Comment: @PeterCsala Thanks you were spot on. I am relatively new to mocking frameworks. Getting the concepts right takes time. I am unsure why fakeUserManager.Setup(x => x.AddClaimsAsync(createUser, claims)).ReturnsAsync(IdentityResult.Success) is returning null however.

Comment: @geekman The question is not mentioning `fakeUserManager` at all. I would suggest to use `It.IsAny` in your `Setup` statements, like this: `userManagerMock.Setup(mgr => mgr.AddClaimsAsync(It.IsAny<User>(), It.IsAny<Claims>())).ReturnsAsync(IdentityResult.Success);`. That means your mock will always return Success independently what have been sent as the parameter.

Comment: @PeterCsala correct again, thanks

Comment: @geekman I've left a post where I've detailed several ways how can you setup and verify method calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Setup phase

Whenever you need to mock an interface method try be permissive during setup.
In other words allow to receive any parameter:

```cs
const string mockedForgotPwdTemplate = "...";
emailTemplate
  .Setup(template => template.GetForgotPasswordTemplate(It.IsAny<EmailTemplateViewModel>()))
  .Returns(mockedForgotPwdTemplate);
```

If your return value depends on the parameter
then use that overload of the `Returns`, which accepts a function:

```cs
const string mockedTemplateWithSubject = "..."; 
const string mockedTemplateWithoutSubject = "...";

emailTemplate
  .Setup(template => template.GetForgotPasswordTemplate(It.IsAny<EmailTemplateViewModel>()))
  .Returns((EmailTemplateViewModel vm) => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.Subject) ? mockedTemplateWithSubject : mockedTemplateWithoutSubject);
```

#### Verification phase

During assertion try to be as specific as possible.
If you have access to the parameter then pass that on to the `Verify`:

```cs
var mockedViewTemplate = new EmailTemplateViewModel { ... };

emailTemplate
  .Verify(template => template.GetForgotPasswordTemplate(mockedViewTemplate), Times.Once);
```

Please bear in mind that moq uses reference check to determine that the `expected` and `actual` parameter are the same. If you don't have a reference to this parameter then you should use `It.Is<T>`:

```cs
const string expectedSubject = "ForgotPassword";

emailTemplate
  .Verify(template => template.GetForgotPasswordTemplate(
     It.Is<EmailTemplateViewModel>(vm => expectedSubject == vm.Subject), Times.Once);
```

or if you wish to assert on more than one attribute then:

```cs
private bool AssertViewModel(EmailTemplateViewModel actualVM, string expectedSubject, string expectedRecipientName)
{
   Assert.Equal(expectedSubject, actualVM.Subject);
   Assert.Equal(expectedRecipientName, actualVM.RecipientName);

   return true;
}  

//...

const string expectedSubject = "ForgotPassword", expectedRecipent = "...";

emailTemplate
  .Verify(template => template.GetForgotPasswordTemplate(
     It.Is<EmailTemplateViewModel>(vm => this.AssertViewModel(vm, expectedSubject, expectedRecipient)), Times.Once);
```